# Trouble with Popen.communication closing the subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to use something like Popen.communicate without closing the subprocess

I've tried using something like 
p.stdin.write(b'foo')

but that doesn't actually pipe it through stdin until I do p.stdin.close()

Here is my code so far:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('bedrock_server.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    process.communicate(input().encode())
```

I would like to use Popen.communicate without it closing the subprocess but instead after inputting one line it closes the subprocess

Comment: try `p.stdin.flush()` or write with ENTER at the end - `"\n"` - `p.stdin.write(b'foo\n')`

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, I tried both potential solutions, thanks tho

Comment: I tried both solutions together and it worked! Thank you so much thank you thank you thank you